# Maven : Different JAR version issue (Generated jar is having different version)

Tags: java, maven, maven-3, dependency-management, maven-shade-plugin

Today I got a strange issue regarding Maven dependency(v:3.6.3) resolution.
I need to have a "net.minidev:json-smart:2.4.7" in my fat jar.
When I do "mvn dependency: tree (v:3.1.1)" it gives me the correct version of the above jar.

```
[INFO] |     +- net.minidev:json-smart:jar:2.4.7:compile
[INFO] |     |  \- net.minidev:accessors-smart:jar:2.4.7:compile
[INFO] |     |     \- org.ow2.asm:asm:jar:9.1:compile
```

And also when I run "mvn clean install -DskipTests" the maven shade plugin (v:3.2.1)
It gives below statement

```
[INFO] Including net.minidev:json-smart:jar:2.4.7 in the shaded jar.
```

But when I extract the generated jar in the target folder.

```
jar xf my.jar META-INF/
cat META-INF/maven/net.minidev/json-smart/pom.properties
```

I am getting below output

```
#Generated by org.apache.felix.bundleplugin
#Sun Oct 19 22:57:53 CEST 2014
version=1.3.1
groupId=net.minidev
artifactId=json-smart
```

I can not figure out why is this happening, I tried to check with dependency:tree and  dependency:build-classpath both are giving me the same version of json-smart jar (v:2.4.7)

But the generated jar is giving me a different version.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include the `pom.xml` file and the commands you use to create the `jar` file.

Comment: Sorry @Progman, I won't be able to post the pom file, as it contains a lot of transitive poms, but somehow I got the reason behind that, I will try to post it in the answer.

Comment: Can you explain what you mean by: `Maven dependency(v:3.6.3)..` ?

Comment: @AkhileshSoni Could you mind sharing the reason for different version inclusion? I too facing the exact same problem.